# git dependency graph is unresolvable; found these conflicting requirements: Dependencies: How to avoid?

Tags: git, swift-package-manager

i created a repository on github with https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-repository/ this help, then i uploaded my project to github with these instructions:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "HelloKit library"
git tag v0.1.0
git remote add origin git@github.com:example/HelloKit.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
git push --tags
```

But after that when i ran command swift package update with this Package.swift file

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Dependencies",
    products: [
        .library(name: "Dependencies", type: .dynamic, targets: ["Dependencies"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/ralfebert/HelloKit.git", from: "0.1.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "Dependencies", dependencies: ["HelloKit"], path: "." )
    ]
)
```

I got an error:

```
Updating https://github.com/ralfebert/HelloKit.git
error: dependency graph is unresolvable; found these conflicting requirements: Dependencies:
```

Who knows what I did wrong?

Comment: Most likely this is a problem with your Package.swift file and not with git.

Comment: you can see my Package.json file whats wrong with them at first glance?

Comment: No this is definitely problem with git (i think i did something wrong because i tried to install another git and everything worked out)

Comment: I am not familiar with Swift, so I can't help there. And I don't see anything wrong with your git commands. Hopefully someone with some Swift knowledge will contribute. What do you mean that you "installed another git"?

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Did it not tell you which conflicting requirements it found? Here's some people with similar issues: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-WebSocket/issues/41 and https://github.com/kylef/Commander/issues/64

Comment: Is your package really named "Dependencies"? When I run `swift build` with your `Packages.swift` I get `.../tmp/Dependencies/Package.swift:11:5: error: argument 'targets' must precede argument 'dependencies'`.

Comment: It is definitely *not* a Git issue. Git does not do dependency graphs.